# Observers in different planets viewing each other

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

I'm a newbie to relativity, so If the question is idiotic, please excuse me.
My question is, as in Interstellar movie suppose one person is sitting in a planet A whose 1 hour equals to 6 years of another planet B where another person is sitting. And if they look at each other using a telescope, what will be each others perspective? I mean the if the person in planet A looks for 1 hour can he see that other person growing old 6 years? and what will the person in planet B see when he looks at person in planet A. Thanks.

Comment: What does "a planet A whose 1 hour equals 6 years of another planet B" mean?

Comment: I mean if you spent 1 hour in planet A, which will be the same as you spending 6 years in planet B. And suppose planet B is earth and two are looking at each other.

Comment: How can an hour in one place be "the same" as six hours in another place?

Comment: That's what confusing me really. As Einstein's twin paradox, where one kid grow old and other remains the same, isn't it because of in space ship time moves slower and in earth it's normal. So when the kid on earth spend 70 years, which will be equivalent to some small amount of time for the other kid in spaceship.

Comment: In the twin "paradox", two twins take different routes from one event to another and register different proper times for the length of the journey.  Suppose you and I travel from Chicago to New York by different routes, and our odometers show different lengths for the journey.  Does that mean that 1 mile in my car is "the same" as 60 miles in your car?

Comment: OK, let's simplify the question as like this. Suppose there are two planets where in planet A time moves very slowly because of high gravity and in planet B it's faster. And if two persons in this planet looks each other, how they will see each other's action?

Comment: What does "time moves very slowly" mean?  We don't ordinarily think of time as something that's capable of motion.

Comment: The "gravitational time dilation effect."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Suppose one person is sitting in a planet A whose 1 hour equals to 6 years of another planet B where another person is sitting. And if they look at each other using a telescope, what will be each others perspective?*

The first guy A will see the second guy B living a "fast forward" life, while the second guy B will see the first guy A living a "slow motion" life.

*I mean the if the person in planet A looks for 1 hour can he see that other person growing old 6 years?*

Yes. If person A kept looking for say ten hours he'd see person B grow old and die.

*and what will the person in planet B see when he looks at person in planet A.*

Very little. Person B sees person A hardly moving at all. Note that the situation for gravitational time dilation isn't symmetrical like the twins paradox. Both observers agree that the guy on planet A is living his life slower than the guy on planet B. *Much* slower.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for... I thought both will see each other as normal. Fast forward and slow motion was hard to grasp for me.